# UpdatePanel, Placeholder, User Control loaded by Ajax post

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I can successfully add a user control dynamically using the following code.

ASPX:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind:

```
UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl
("~/App_Controls/Site/Player/PlayerProfile2.ascx");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Now I want to load the user in response to a button click. I have code that submits a form by doing an ajax post.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options =
    {
        success: showResponse,
        url: "/Default.aspx",
        type: "post"
    };

    $('#btnClick').click(function () {
        $("form").ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
});

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) 
{
    alert(responseText);
}

<asp:Button ID="btnClick" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Click" />

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
<asp:Literal ID="litText" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am a newbie to C#. When the placeholder or the literal are changed I w

Comment: Hi, if you found my answer helpful, it would've great if you could mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!  If not, let me know how I can improve it and I'd be glad to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using jQuery AJAX, I would use the built in ASP.NET AJAX; it will provide a simpler experience for you.  http://weblogs.asp.net/sanjeevagarwal/archive/2008/07/22/Dynamically-create-ASP.NET-user-control-using-ASP.NET-Ajax-and-Web-Service.aspx.  By moving the button inside the UpdatePanel, any PostBack that the button generates will be intercepted by the .NET framework and submitted as a partial postback (using AJAX).  This should give you a solid starting point for how to achieve what you're after using the .NET AJAX style.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Click" />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
<asp:Literal ID="litText" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the CodeBehind file, you can use `IsPostBack` to conditionally show or hide your user control.

However, if you'd prefer to stick with your current approach, this blog has a good example that's more complete than what I could type here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-load-and-display-ASPNet-UserControl-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-WebMethod.aspx

Answer (score 0):

UserControls (ASCX) get attached to the page during server-side rendering and cannot be created with Javascript the way standard HTML elements can. I would suggest using a div containing standard HTML elements as opposed to a user control and using a Javascript library such as Jquery to create copies of this div when applicable.